# How to give Worklight Server access to MySQL (SQL adapter)

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm migrating a worklight app from 5.0.3 to 5.0.6.

I tried to add

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar** to worklight.war

file but I get the following **error**:

> Procedure invocation error. Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform or project
>   /worklight

Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why to the .war file? Add more information to your question: are you running Worklight in Eclipse or on an application Server (Tomcat/Liberty/WAS)?

If you are using the Worklight Developer Edition (essentially plug-in download for Eclipse):

- You need to place `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar` to the \lib
  folder of your project... located at: `yourProject\server\lib`.
- Make sure to also update the datasource definitions in the adapter XML:

> ```
> <dataSourceDefinition>
>     <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
>     <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>
>     <user>myUsername</user>
>     <password>myPassword</password> 
> </dataSourceDefinition>
> ```

If you are using Worklight by deploying it to an Application Server (Tomcat/Libery/WAS), the above actions will also update the .war file, located in `yourProject\bin`, which you will need to **redeploy to your application server**.

Comment: I did use IBM installation manager to install Worklight with DB2 database. the problem is I want to migrate an application that uses Mysql database into the worklight server that's been installed using DB2. the question is the following; Can I migrate this application even though it uses Mysql database (try to interface with DB2)? Or I have to change the database implementation, meaning I have to re-implement the database in DB2 instead of Mysql

Comment: You'll have to migrate your DB2 databas to MySQL. Worklight does not provide such conversion scripts.