# IBM Worklight database connection

Tags: mysql, db2, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed Worklight Server and with DB2 database, and now I try to migrate an application that has a MySQL database which is obviously not working. Is there any workaround? Do I have to use an adapter to interface the DB2 and MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database usually requires a **connector driver** in order to interface with it.

Had you used the IBM Installation Manager to install Worklight with DB2 database (available to IBM Worklight customers, are you one?), it would require you to supply such a driver, so I will assume - **since you did not provide any information on your environment setup** - that you are using the Development Edition (Eclipse + Worklight Studio plug-in).

In this case you need to edit the `worklight.properties` file (can be found in Eclipse under  yourProject\server\conf).

- Change the database type to DB2 (ucomment it) and [supply the required information](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_ibm_worklight_properties.html) based on your environment.

The DB2 connector [can be download through this page](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866). Get the correct version for your installation of DB2.

- Place the driver in the lib folder (can be found in Eclipse under yourProject\server).

If you are in fact using Liberty or WebSphere, [see this troubleshooting section with installation instructions for DB2 and more](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_db2_manually.html).

Comment: I did use IBM installation manager to install Worklight with DB2 database. My challenge is

Comment: I did use IBM installation manager to install Worklight with DB2 database. the problem is I want to migrate an application that uses Mysql database into the worklight server that's been installed using DB2. the question is the following; Can I migrate this application even though it uses Mysql database (try to interface with DB2)? Or I have to change the database implementation, meaning I have to re-implement the database in DB2 instead of Mysql?

Comment: there is no migration path. Why have two questions one this matter? keep only 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337591/how-to-give-worklight-server-access-to-mysql-sql-adapter/16337929?noredirect=1#comment23698261_16337929